# Is moving the target of a raw Pointer safe in rust

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, raw-pointer

I'm creating a bidirectional graph in rust and the parent pointer are an obvious problem with the rust borrowing rules so I used raw pointers which are in theory safe since the parent owns the child and cannot be dropped before the child. The only problem I have (in my head) is when the graph moves. If the graph moves all parent pointer should be invalid as they point into the old location of the graph.

But testing by example showed me different results. Not only where the old pointer still valid the debugger also showed a new entry in "Register>Effective Address" which mapped old pointer to new location.
My test code:

```
fn main() -> Result<()> {

    let m = test();
    println!("MT:{}, IT:{}, PTR_MT:{}", m.j, m.inner.i, unsafe {(*m.inner.parent).j});
    Ok(())
}


fn test() -> Box<MyType> {
    let mut mytype = MyType { inner: MyInnerType { parent: std::ptr::null_mut(), i: 5 }, j:69 };
    println!("MT:{}, IT:{}", mytype.j, mytype.inner.i);
    mytype.inner.parent = &mut mytype;

    Box::new(mytype)
} 


struct MyType {
    inner: MyInnerType,
    j:i32
}

struct MyInnerType {
    parent: *mut MyType,
    i:i32
}
```

Is this behavior defined and can I rely on it working?

Comment: The way you wrote it [MIRI] in the top right under [TOOLS] of the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=767f3063f80eeae3b183b28582e14dd5) detects UB. `Box::new(mytype)` moves `mytype` and invalidates all references & pointers to it.

Comment: cafce25 thanks, that answers the question rather it's ub or not. This leaves me with the question on how to fix this. Preferably without creating a disjoint heap structure. Updating all pointers would be possible but I don't see a reliable way to trigger the update.

Comment: Raw pointers are safe until you try to dereference them, so if you're trying to isolate the point of unsafety, it would be where the raw pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: I just found a dead simple solution. I just made the root allocated on the heap and prevented any access to the owning box making the pointers last as long as the tree does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not safe. It is unsound and exhibits undefined behavior. "The program works as intended" is one possible outcome, but it is not the only one.

`Box::new(mytype)` moves `mytype` into a heap allocation, which is not UB. However, evaluating `*m.inner.parent` later causes UB as the pointer target has been moved.

You should generally avoid raw pointers in Rust unless you are either implementing a safe abstraction on top of them or you are using FFI and cannot accomplish what you need to without them.